# how to add JVM option -Xss512m to spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark

How to add JVM option -Xss512m to spark-submit?

In other words, where do I have to use `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`?

Answer (score 6):

The Java options have to be specified via the `conf` parameter so ideally what you will be doing is:

```
spark-submit --class YOUR_MAIN_CLASS --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss512m" 
                                     --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss512m" APP.jar
```

Comment: I believe you mean Xmx and Xms

Comment: Nope. I think the question was about the thread stack size `Xss` so the same is conveyed in the answer.

Comment: I have been struggling with StackOverflow error due to my deeply nested conditions in Spark - this has helped me a great deal. Thanks @SivaprasannaSethuraman